# Syntax Error: "faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale( ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax "

Tags: python, syntax-error, face-recognition, face-detection

I'm trying to detect faces from images using Haar Cascades in opencv and getting Syntax Error while running the below snippet.

```
import cv2
import os

imagePath = os.path.abspath("C:\\Users\\rohit\\Desktop\\Project\\1.jpg")
cascPath = os.path.abspath("C:\\Users\\rohit\\Desktop\\Project\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY

faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
    gray,
    scaleFactor=1.1,
    minNeighbors=5,
    minSize=(30, 30),
    
)

for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

filename = 'myconvertedimage.jpg'
  
cv2.imwrite(filename, image)
```

Comment: Missed closing parenthesis in line `gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY`. Code should be `gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

Answer (score 1):

u missed the closing bracket in line`gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY`